# Java Array list synchronization if written in one thread and read in another

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I have a controller class that runs in thread A and composes a local variable list like this

Thread A

```
list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Order>>();
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
```

where Order is a java bean with several primitive properties like String, int, long, etc.

Once this list is constructed, its reference is passed to a UI thread (thread B) of Activity and accessed there. The cross-thread communication is done using a Handler class + post() method.

So the question is, can I access the list data from thread B without synchronization at all? Please note, that after constructed in thread A, the list will not be accessed/modified at all. It just exists like a local variable and is passed to thread B afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the context you provide that where does this happen:

```
list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Order>>();
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
```

If it is in a constructor **and** `list` is `final` **and** the `this` reference does not leak from the constructor **and** you are absolutely sure that `list` won't change (for example by using the `unmodifiableList` decorator method) **and** the references to the `Order` instances are not accessible from elsewhere than it may be OK to not use synchronization. Otherwise you have Sword of Damocles over your head.

I mentioned the `Order` references because you may not get exceptions if you change them from somewhere else but it may lead to data inconsistency/corruption.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe. The synchronization done at the message queue establishes a happens-before relationship. This of course assumes that you don't modify the Maps either afterwards. Also any objects contained in the maps, and so on must not be modified by other threads without proper synchronization.

In short, if the list and none of the data within it are not modified by other threads than B, you don't need any further synchronization.

Comment: What kind of message queue are you talking about? OP does not mention any.

Comment: @AdamArold He mentions Handler. That uses MessageQueue.

Comment: That does not protect him from someone else's modification which might happen in the future and leads to the explosion of the application.

Comment: @AdamArold correct, but he mentions the list itself is not modified (locally created, maybe, so that there won't be other references), and I mention the requirement of not modifying the maps - I'll extend it to objects contained in those maps too. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the list will not be modified then you don't need synchonization since all threads will always see the same List.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, no need to synchronize if you're only going to read the data.

Note that even if thread A is going to eventually modify the list while thread B (or any other number of threads) is accessing it, you still do not have to synchronize because there's only one writer at any given time.

Sorry, the above statement is not *completely* correct. As stated in the JavaDoc:

> If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at
>   least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be
>   synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation
>   that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the
>   backing array; *merely setting the value of an element is not a
>   structural modification*.)

Also note I'm not taking into account element modification but purely list modifications.

Comment: now, that could really blow up iteration. `ConcurrentModificationException` if you're lucky, silent corruption if you are not

Comment: "because there's only one writer at any given time"
Doesn't this violate visibility principle or multi-threading? Yes, there's just one reader, but the data will not be visible to another thread until you synchronize. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. What does visibility has to do with threads?

Comment: Second part of your answer: " if thread A is going to eventually modify the list while thread B (or any other number of threads) is accessing it". For instance, thread B owns the reference to that list, and after that thread A makes some insertions to that list. Thread B won't "see" those changes. Isn't it?

Comment: Of course it will see them after they happen. They're referencing the same list as you said.

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov Sorry, not any modification is acceptable without synchronization. Please see the answer edit.